# Particle effect in cocos2d ios game

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, particles

I am a new hand in developing game in cocos2d, and I use the class CCRenderTexture in my game. Does this class support particle effects? I now have a particle effect, and I want to it to be implemented in a CCRenderTexture I defined. Is there anybody that can share some related documents or code, or your opinion on it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The ever helpful Steffen Itterheim wrote an excellent tutorial with examples on multiple usages of CCRenderTexture, including how to render nodes onto it using begin/visit/end.

http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/how-to-use-ccrendertexture-motion-blur-screenshots-drawing-sketches/

Hopefully this gets you started with how to apply CCParticleSystem nodes onto your RTT.

Comment: glad it helped! feel free to accept the answer if that resolved your question.